# How to verified .mobileconfig file?

Tags: ios, file, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have create one .mobileconfig file using the Apple Configurator.
When I install this file in iOS device, It show "Not Verified".

[image]

So, How can Verified this ?

Answer (score 2):

Check in terminal for certificates which can be used to sign the profile by using below command.

```
    security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

Then use below command to sign the profile.

```
 /usr/bin/security cms -S -N "[Signing Certificate]" -i "[input]" -o "[output]"
```

EG: - /usr/bin/security cms -S -N "signing certificate(generally developer id)" -i 'path of unsigned profile' -o 'path of copy of unsigned profile'

Note - Two mobileconfig file should be there one for input & other for output. It will not create new profile. It will just sign the output profile with the values of input profile.

Comment: Any idea how to use this in a XCode project and sign the profile programmatically?